# Showing $\sqrt{2} \notin E.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $E$ denote the least subring of $\mathbb{R}$ that is closed under the operation $r \mapsto e^r$. Then presumably, $\sqrt{2} \notin E.$

> **Question.** How can we show this?

Comment: Smells like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: You don't need the disclaimer about the identity, given that $1=e^0$. :)

Comment: Can you add little more context to the question ?

Comment: @G.T.R, I guess so. What kind of context are you looking for? To rephrase the question, I want to see a proof that we cannot build $\sqrt{2}$ using just $+,\times,0,1$ and $x \mapsto e^x$.

Comment: No one has proved that $e^{e^{e^{e^{e}}}}$ is not an integer; makes me think this will likewise be open.

Comment: @JonasMeyer, so you're saying that no one has proved that the sequence $e,e^e, e^{e^e},\ldots$ never encounters an integer?

Comment: Yes, more specifically, even the number in my comment has not been proven to not be an integer. "Presumably" it isn't.

Comment: @JonasMeyer, why can't we just use numerical tools? It seems kind of straightforward if we're dealing with a *particular* number.

Comment: @goblin:  Too big.  Somewhat similarly, in the ring you ask about, you will get numbers whose distance to sqrt 2 is too small to distinguish numerically.